# Why is this inference incorrect?

Tags: first-order-logic

I wasn't sure if this was [the correct place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194693/where-to-ask-question-about-logic) to post my question, but here goes:

Formally, why are these inferences incorrect?

```
All men are people;

Half of all people are women;

Therefore, half of all men are women.

-----

Penguins are black and white;

Some old TV shows are black and white;

Therefore, some penguins are old TV shows.
```

Comment: 1) Because you cannot use "half of" as a quantifier, as your couter-example show it. A *valid* argument is one that from *true* premises* derives a *true* conclusion: the above conclusion is *false*; thus, the argument is not valid.

Comment: These are all of the form "x implies y"  "z sometimes can be y" Therefore "z is sometimes x".  This doesn't follow because although x implies y, it doesn't in the least bit mean that y implies x.  All elephants live on land.  Mikey mouse lives on land.  Therefore Mikey mouse is an elephant.  That is *exactly* the same argument and exactly as valid for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: Using set notation the argument goes $X \subset Y $ and $S\cup Y \ne \emptyset $. Therefore $S\cup X \ne \emptyset $. It's not valid because .... it's crap.

Answer (score 1):

See [Aristotle’s logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) for the notion of *deduction* (*sullogismos*).

Aristotle says:

> A deduction is speech (*logos*) in which, certain things having been supposed, something different from those supposed results of necessity because of their being so. (*Prior Analytics* I.2, 24b18–20)

Each of the “things supposed” is a *premise* of the argument, and what “results of necessity” is the *conclusion*.

This is the source of the notion of [valid argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity) :

> In logic, an argument is valid if and only if it takes a form that makes it impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion to be false.

The above examples, being both examples of true premises and false conclusion shows that the corresponding arguments are not valid.

For the second one, see [Fallacy of the undistributed middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_undistributed_middle).